# Clear Chicagoboss cache

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I have been using `erlang` and `chicagoboss` since 5-6 months. I have observed that when I don't run `./rebar compile` for long time then server takes too much load. requires at least `20 -25 seconds` to reload any of the web page on `localhost`.

My questions are:

- What happens when I run  `./rebar compile`?
- Why it takes small time after I run this command?(as far as I know
  this compiles something.)
- Is there anything which I can do to minimise the loading time in
  chicagoboss.
- We're using `memcache` and `Cowboy`. Does it anything to do with
  memcache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you are using `./init-dev.sh`. This scripts provides automatic reloading, which is really great during development, but can be slow. It checks all the `.beam` files and if corresponding `.erl` file was modified later, it means, that it has to be recompiled. Recompilation takes place on every request. It doesn't actually create new `.beam` files in the place of the previous ones. It compiles them "on the fly" and loads, so even, if you did not change anything after first modification, the file still has to be recompiled.

If you did some modifications to bigger number of files, this operation might have big impact on your system. It probably doesn't have anything to do with memcache or Cowboy. Just compile the files regularly.

A few tricks:

- `./rebar compile` can be slow, because it goes through all the dependencies, try `./rebar compile skip_deps=true`. This is much faster!
- If you *did* modify CB files and want to compile them, you still don't have to wait, try `./rebar compile apps=your_app_name,boss`. You have to compile all the apps, that use that dependency, so if you modified `boss_db`, you have to invoke: `./rebar compile apps=your_app_name,boss,boss_db`.
- You can use hot code reload on production. After compiling invoke `./init.sh reload`, but it *doesn't work with memcache*! The memcache driver is not proper OTP application and after hot code reload, it does not get updated. After second hot code reload processes using old code are purged and the connection to memcache is lost. So if you are using memcache, don't use hot code reload.